# I want to make full width of all cms page. now it is max-width of 1280px. i want to make it to 1720px. how can i change

Tags: magento2.4, cms-pages, home-page, custom-theme, full-width

I want to change max-width, but it is not overriding in custom-theme. how can i change

Here is the css style .

```
@media (min-width: 768px), print
.navigation, .breadcrumbs, .page-header .header.panel, .header.content, .footer.content, .page-wrapper > .widget, .page-wrapper > .page-bottom, .block.category.event, .top-container, .page-main {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 1280px; 
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Is that a custom css file? If that's it you should declare this piece of css code after the "Not media" one

Answer (score 0):

You need to override layout max-width.
Main layout file is:
 **lib/web/css/source/lib/variables/_layout.less**

You can overide below value at your theme path:
 **app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/source/_theme.less**

```
@layout__max-width: 1720px;
```